# Bold and Italic Function for Open Editiot

Tags: javascript, html

i am makin an Editior in HTML using Javascript . here i made code for "BOLD" function but it not working .

```
function bold()

{

    var txt = document.getElementById("plain").value;

    document.getElementById("plain").value = "<b>"+txt+"</b>";

    document.getElementById("plain").innerHTML = document.getElementById("plain").value;

}


<div id="view" align="center" style="width: 50%; height: 53%; top: 65%" >
<button type="button" align="bottom" onclick="bold(";>Bold</button>
```

Comment: Please show the relevant HTML for the object with id="plain".

Answer (score 0):

Hmm first you don't have an element with the id="plain" anywhere in your example, second, you're missing a closing div tag for the id="view", and third, your button params has an `onclick="bold(";` which won't do anything but spit an error at you.

Comment: <div id="view" align="center" style="width: 50%; height: 53%; top: 65%" >
<button type="button" align="bottom" onclick="bold(";>Bold</button>
<button type="button" align="bottom">Italic</button>
<button type="button" align="bottom">Underline</button><br>
<textarea id="plain" rows="13" cols="50">

</textarea>